# How to select specific column using Linq with certain condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm executing two stored procedures and comparing results. Each stored procs results are defined in its own class.

The question is how to I select specific field 'AreaId' with the defined filter?

```
var a = new List<aDrivingCursor>();
//execute stored proc 1
sp.Execute(out aDrivingCursor);

var b = new List<bDrivingCursor>();
//execute stored proc 2
sp2.Execute(out bDrivingCursor);

foreach (var temp in aDrivingCursor)
{
    int areaId = 0                       
    if (b.Any(s => s.Address1 == temp.Address1))
    {
        //This is where I'm having problem with
        areaId = Int32.Parse(b
            .Where(s => s.Address1 == a.Address1)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Select(o => o.AreaId));    
    }
}
```

Here is my classes:

```
class aDrivingCursor
{
    public String Address1 { get; set; }
}

class bDrivingCursor
{
    public int AreaId { get; set; }

    public String Address1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? what issues are you getting right now with this code?

Comment: Why are you trying to `Int32.Parse` an `AreaId` if it's already an `int`?

Comment: You should have that `Select` before the `FirstOrDefault`.  Or just `FirstOrDefault()?.AreaId ?? 0`.

Comment: @jPhizzle you are correct I'm missing Address1 on bDrivingCursor. Address1 is actually type String

Comment: The error that I got is cannot convert from Int to String.

Comment: That's because you're selecting an `int` and trying to pass it to `Int32.Parse`, which expects a `string`.

Comment: I second @RufusL's observation

Comment: `int areaId = b.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Address1 == temp.Address1)?.AreaId ?? 0;`